Coroutines - receive new data only ones and then stop subscribing a flow
in my android project I'd like to receive new data only once, after subscribing a flow, and then stop subscribing. I know something about hot flows (SharedFlow).
My goals:

try to emit the data (without suspending)
subscribe producer
receive new data, not historical, only once
stop subscribing

My simplified code:
    class Producer {
        private val _event = MutableSharedFlow<String>(
            extraBufferCapacity = 1,
            onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
        )
        val event: Flow<String> = _event.asSharedFlow()
    
        fun produce(event: String) {
            _event.tryEmit(event)
        }
    }
    
    class Consumer {
        val producer = Producer()
        var job: Job? = null
    
        fun consume(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) {
            job = producer
                .event
                .onEach {
                    job?.cancel()
                    // process
                }
                .launchIn(viewModelScope)
        }
    }



It works, but IMO some functions could be replaced by others e.g.:

if only once I want to receive the data, so it should be another function instead of onEach
instead of storing reference to Job and calling launchIn I tried to call .shareIn(viewModelScope, WhileSubscribed())

    .onEach {
        // job?.cancel() <- removed it
        // process
    }
    .shareIn(viewModelScope, WhileSubscribed())

but it doesn't work ..
How can I improve my code?

To rule out this being an XY-Problem, why do you even want that? This looks highly unusual and not what flows are designed to do. Can you [edit] your question and describe in more detail what actual problem you want to solve with this?

If you only need the first item from a flow then there is the first function for it:
producer.event.first()

It does exactly what you said - it waits for the first item, then it unsubscribes.

Have you tried .take(2)?  That would return a flow that returns only the first 2 elements of the parent flow.  So if foo is a StateFlow, then foo.take(2) would return a flow that emits only the initial value and the next update.  foo.take(2).onEach{} would allow you to run a lambda on each of those 2 elements.
